# ubuntu in openvz, file creation has a future time

Tags: ubuntu, time, future, createfile, openvz

I have a ubuntu 10.04 system in a openvz contaioner.

now, I get a problem of the time & time zone.

I have change my timezone to Asia/Shanghai by the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

and it get work when I run command:

```
~$ date
2013年 02月 24日 星期日 12:00:05 CST
```

But if I touch a file, the file's modifier time is in the future!

```
~$ touch somefile
~$ ls -l
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 chen chen 0 2013-02-24 20:07 somefile
```

Note that the new touched file `somefile` has a 8 hours future time!! how it happend!!

```
~$ ls --full-time
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 chen chen 0 2013-02-24 20:07:33.340285883 +0800 somefile
```

Answer (score 0):

Touch hasn't been aliased has it? That is the command touch isn't an alias for touch -d '+8 hours' or something like that?

Comment: normal create file such as `vim newfile` will cause the same problem.

Comment: The system is just a new installed system. All things are right at First. Just When I changed my TimeZone, the problem occured.

Comment: Ok, then the hardware clock is most probably set to Singapore and the TimeZone is adding an extra 8 hours to it. This might help you out http://forum.openvz.org/index.php?t=msg&th=1662&start=0&

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I checked my vps host's TimeZone. It is the +8 zone. So I think the `touch` command use the host's timezone, +8 hours to the GMT time, then in the vps, +8 hours again. May I change the Host's TimeZone to GMT TimeZone?

Comment: Your hardware clock on the host should be UTC/GMT then the timezone should be set correctly on that host and the VPS also. So they should both read the hardware clock and adjust their time according to the timezone.